# Accessing only the body of an email using python

Tags: python, email

I am trying to access only the body of an email and have managed to get this using the email module and the email.getpayload() function. The only issue is that there seems to be 'junk text' that shows up and it seems to be in a different format, amount and content depending on who sends the email. Is there a way to access only the true body of an email? thanks!

This is what I have:

```
msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    body = ''
    if msg.is_multipart():
        for part in msg.walk():
            if part.is_multipart():
                for subpart in part.get_payload():
                    if subpart.is_multipart():
                        for subsubpart in subpart.get_payload():
                            body = body +     str(subsubpart.get_payload(decode=True)) + '\n'
                    else:
                        body = body + str(subpart.get_payload(decode=True)) + '\n'
            else:
                body = body + str(part.get_payload(decode=True)) + '\n'

    else:
        body = body + str(msg.get_payload(decode=True)) + '\n'
```

Comment: What is the actual *junk text* you are referring to?

Comment: Is your e-mail a multipart message? I.e. does it have an attachment or image or custom background or unusual font or something like that

Comment: Did you use m.get_payload(decode=True)???

Answer (score 0):

```
from email import message_from_file
import os

# Path to directory where attachments will be stored:
path = "./msgfiles"

# To have attachments extracted into memory, change behaviour of 2 following functions:

def file_exists (f):
    """Checks whether extracted file was extracted before."""
    return os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, f))

def save_file (fn, cont):
    """Saves cont to a file fn"""
    file = open(os.path.join(path, fn), "wb")
    file.write(cont)
    file.close()

def construct_name (id, fn):
    """Constructs a file name out of messages ID and packed file name"""
    id = id.split(".")
    id = id[0]+id[1]
    return id+"."+fn

def disqo (s):
    """Removes double or single quotations."""
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith("'") and s.endswith("'"): return s[1:-1]
    if s.startswith('"') and s.endswith('"'): return s[1:-1]
    return s

def disgra (s):
    """Removes < and > from HTML-like tag or e-mail address or e-mail ID."""
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith("<") and s.endswith(">"): return s[1:-1]
    return s

def pullout (m, key):
    """Extracts content from an e-mail message.
    This works for multipart and nested multipart messages too.
    m   -- email.Message() or mailbox.Message()
    key -- Initial message ID (some string)
    Returns tuple(Text, Html, Files, Parts)
    Text  -- All text from all parts.
    Html  -- All HTMLs from all parts
    Files -- Dictionary mapping extracted file to message ID it belongs to.
    Parts -- Number of parts in original message.
    """
    Html = ""
    Text = ""
    Files = {}
    Parts = 0
    if not m.is_multipart():
        if m.get_filename(): # It's an attachment
            fn = m.get_filename()
            cfn = construct_name(key, fn)
            Files[fn] = (cfn, None)
            if file_exists(cfn): return Text, Html, Files, 1
            save_file(cfn, m.get_payload(decode=True))
            return Text, Html, Files, 1
        # Not an attachment!
        # See where this belongs. Text, Html or some other data:
        cp = m.get_content_type()
        if cp=="text/plain": Text += m.get_payload(decode=True)
        elif cp=="text/html": Html += m.get_payload(decode=True)
        else:
            # Something else!
            # Extract a message ID and a file name if there is one:
            # This is some packed file and name is contained in content-type header
            # instead of content-disposition header explicitly
            cp = m.get("content-type")
            try: id = disgra(m.get("content-id"))
            except: id = None
            # Find file name:
            o = cp.find("name=")
            if o==-1: return Text, Html, Files, 1
            ox = cp.find(";", o)
            if ox==-1: ox = None
            o += 5; fn = cp[o:ox]
            fn = disqo(fn)
            cfn = construct_name(key, fn)
            Files[fn] = (cfn, id)
            if file_exists(cfn): return Text, Html, Files, 1
            save_file(cfn, m.get_payload(decode=True))
        return Text, Html, Files, 1
    # This IS a multipart message.
    # So, we iterate over it and call pullout() recursively for each part.
    y = 0
    while 1:
        # If we cannot get the payload, it means we hit the end:
        try:
            pl = m.get_payload(y)
        except: break
        # pl is a new Message object which goes back to pullout
        t, h, f, p = pullout(pl, key)
        Text += t; Html += h; Files.update(f); Parts += p
        y += 1
    return Text, Html, Files, Parts

def extract (msgfile, key):
    """Extracts all data from e-mail, including From, To, etc., and returns it as a dictionary.
    msgfile -- A file-like readable object
    key     -- Some ID string for that particular Message. Can be a file name or anything.
    Returns dict()
    Keys: from, to, subject, date, text, html, parts[, files]
    Key files will be present only when message contained binary files.
    For more see __doc__ for pullout() and caption() functions.
    """
    m = message_from_file(msgfile)
    From, To, Subject, Date = caption(m)
    Text, Html, Files, Parts = pullout(m, key)
    Text = Text.strip(); Html = Html.strip()
    msg = {"subject": Subject, "from": From, "to": To, "date": Date,
        "text": Text, "html": Html, "parts": Parts}
    if Files: msg["files"] = Files
    return msg

def caption (origin):
    """Extracts: To, From, Subject and Date from email.Message() or mailbox.Message()
    origin -- Message() object
    Returns tuple(From, To, Subject, Date)
    If message doesn't contain one/more of them, the empty strings will be returned.
    """
    Date = ""
    if origin.has_key("date"): Date = origin["date"].strip()
    From = ""
    if origin.has_key("from"): From = origin["from"].strip()
    To = ""
    if origin.has_key("to"): To = origin["to"].strip()
    Subject = ""
    if origin.has_key("subject"): Subject = origin["subject"].strip()
    return From, To, Subject, Date
```

```
Usage:
f = open("message.eml", "rb")
print extract(f, f.name)
f.close()
```

I programmed this for my mailgroup using mailbox, that is why it is so convoluted. It never failed me. Never any junk. If message is multipart, output dictionary will contain a key "files" (a sub dict) with all filenames of extracted other files that were not text or html. That was a way of extracting attachments and other binary data. You may change it in pullout(), or just change the behaviour of file_exists() and save_file(). construct_name() constructs a filename out of message id and multipart message filename, if there is one. Maybe there are some errors here, because it is intended to work with mailbox.Message, not with email.Message. But this is all I have at the moment, and cannot tell you more, until you provide us with more info. Maybe you just forgot decode=True and are getting some rfc822 junky crappy end of file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the decode=true but I think it's both that and the missing handling of multiparty that's giving me trouble!

Comment: I have tried to use the decode=True but every time it only produces a none and never anything of value

Comment: See if msg.is_multipart()==True because if it is, then msg.get_payload(0) will give you everything in 0 part. Did you try my code? If my code gives you odd results as well, then something big is off. From which mailer are the messages you're trying to read? Will you put some of your code here?

Comment: I think the issue is that the mailers are all different, I'll post what I have!

Comment: I edited my code. Found some time and added comments, so, now it makes a little more sense. Your code, essentially, should produce OK output, although it is not done as you did it. See my code, entering nested multipart is done recursively. First save yourself one email, not multipart, to play with normal get_payload(decode=True), then this function call recursively on all parts.

Comment: If you wish, you can easily change my code not to use message_from_file(), and use message_from_bytes() or *_string(). Or you can push StringIO() with your message to it.

Comment: Or maybe it will not. You used a for loop over get_payload() and inside it body = ... What means that body will be None for part which is nNone, if that's something implemented. E.g. for last part. Why didn't you use for subsubpart in subpart.walk()? In any case don't do it that way. Use recursion! Different mailers shouldn't be a problem. E-mail's are pretty standardized, although some discrepancies between Mac OS X Mail and others may occur around attachments.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3, I figure it out based on your recommendations and its working fine now! (I struggled with the from_bytes/from_string for a while)

Comment: Excellent! Sorry if / confused you. Python 2 has message_from_string(), Python's 3 equivalent is message_from_bytes(). That is what I ment.